# C++ reading in a matrix-style text file into a 2D array, keeping only numerical blocks

Tags: c++, arrays, digit

I'm sure this is a very simple task, however I am very new at c++ so this is a little tricky for me..

Anyway, I have a text file, that is already in the form of a 25x14 array (or larger once I get the code figured out). Unfortunately some of the rows have only one entry, which is a word.

What I want to do is move through the text file and map every entry (excluding the rows with a word on them) into a simple array in C++ so I can create histograms, etc.

I am planning on doing this with the isdigit() function.

here is what I have so far:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int str;
    int matrix[25][14]; 

    ifstream inFile("inputfile.txt");

    while (inFile >> str) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++) {                  
                if (isdigit(inFile)) {
                    inFile >> matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which definitely gives plenty of errors.  My problem is I need some function which looks at the txt file one word (delineated by white spaces) at a time.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this :

First define a simple function :

```
bool is_a_bad_line(const std::vector<int>& l)
{
  return l.size() < 14;
}
```

Then :

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > data;
std::ifstream f("inputfile.txt");
std::string line;
while(std::getline(f,line))
{
  std::vector<int> line_data;
  std::istringstream iss(line);
  int value;
  while(iss >> value)
    line_data.push_back(value);
  data.push_back(line_data);
}
std::remove_if(data.begin(), data.end(), is_bad_line);
```

See [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), [istringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream) and [remove_if algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/) to well understand the behaviour.

Comment: Why not test `line.size() = 14` after the while loop and only then push_back rather than always add, then test and remove at the end?

Comment: Thanks! I finally got it to work using what you suggested, thank you!

Comment: @user4581301: it's for modularity. With this implementation, it's easy to change the container, or to change the constraints on the removed lines. But the solution inside the loop is correct too. Actually, I did a mistake in the call of `std::remove_if`, it's now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

let your file has 2 number on each line

```
1 2
2 3 
4 5
```

std::istringstream will get the numbers and store them in variable

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int a, b;
    if (!(iss >> a >> b)) { break; } // error

    // process pair (a,b)
}
```

i know its not a matrix notation , but may help you